# rearrange data frame for calculating ICC

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the ICC for multiple raters scoring multiple students. My data looks similar to:

```
student    rater    Q1    Q2    Q3
stA        raA      4     3     1
stA        raB      1     2     3
stA        raC      2     2     2
stB        raA      3     1     1
...
```

I am wanting to format the data to be like:

```
          raterA       raterB    raterC
stAQ1     4            1         2
stAQ2     3            2         2
stAQ3     1            3         2
stBQ1     3            1         1
...
```

How can I do this. I've tried using `aggregate` and `dcast` but can't get it to work.
Thanks!

Comment: I can never remember how to reshape data, so I've book marked [this page](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/). It shows you how to convert form wide to long and long to wide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the `dcast` approach for data.frame `d`:

```
library(reshape2)
foo <- dcast(melt(d, variable.name='quarter'), student + quarter ~ rater)

foo

#   student quarter raA raB raC
# 1     stA      Q1   4   1   2
# 2     stA      Q2   3   2   2
# 3     stA      Q3   1   3   2
# 4     stB      Q1   3  NA  NA
# 5     stB      Q2   1  NA  NA
# 6     stB      Q3   1  NA  NA
```

If you really want `student` and `variable` combined as row names (although I wouldn't recommend it since it makes further aggregation by student and quarter difficult), then:

```
row.names(foo) <- do.call(paste0, foo[, 1:2])
foo <- foo[, -c(1:2)]
foo

#       raA raB raC
# stAQ1   4   1   2
# stAQ2   3   2   2
# stAQ3   1   3   2
# stBQ1   3  NA  NA
# stBQ2   1  NA  NA
# stBQ3   1  NA  NA
```

Answer (score 2):

And a base R version for good measure:

```
reshape(
 cbind(dat[1:2],stack(dat[-(1:2)])),
 idvar=c("student","ind"), timevar="rater", direction="wide"
)

#   student ind values.raA values.raB values.raC
#1      stA  Q1          4          1          2
#4      stB  Q1          3         NA         NA
#5      stA  Q2          3          2          2
#8      stB  Q2          1         NA         NA
#9      stA  Q3          1          3          2
#12     stB  Q3          1         NA         NA
```